# No SMS notifications windows 10

Tags: windows-10-mobile, sms, notifications

I've upgraded my 640 and have lost SMS notifications. Not sure if it's something I did or not but Settings / System / Notifications & Actions / Messaging is turned on. Battery saver settings have Microsoft phone enabled. Missed calls do show with a counter on the glance screen.

Any ideas how to bring back SMS notifications? I'd rather not hard reset.

Comment: Try checking if "Quiet Hours" is disabled, under Cortana

Comment: Nope, I don't normally have Cortana enabled, but I've turned it on and no difference (quiet hours are off)

Comment: Okay, but you're sure that all the other notifications and sounds from other apps are playing, and it's not a hardware problem??

Comment: Okay it's a bit weird, I am get getting message delivery notifications (after turning the option on) for sent messages from my network operator and those do appear on the lock screen/messages tile.

Comment: Interestingly trying to check the glance screen settings prompted me to do a phone restart to install an update. I'll see if it's fixed anything later on.

Comment: Dunno why but it's started working again after it was left charging overnight. Possibly some weird caching issue todo with the glance screen?

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem when i was on old builds like 10586,136, .164 etc. make sure you are on latest build. these were small bugs. they're all fixed now.

Answer (score 3):

Hey do check these things on your phone:

1. Go to >All settings>System>Notifications & Actions>Messaging (Switch is 'On'). Enter **Messaging** & switch 'On' **Notifications, Show notification banners, Keep notifications private on the lock screen, Vibrate if my sound settings support it**, and choose your **Notification Sound**.
2. Now go to >All settings>Personalisation>Sounds> and switch 'On' **Vibrate** and **MAKE SURE** you have 'tick marked' **System alerts**.

If **System alerts** is not 'ticked' then you will not get some of the alerts from your phone, including messaging notification.

Answer (score 3):

Had that problem too. Follow these steps:

1. Go to *Settings->Battery saver->battery usage*.
2. Select *Messaging + Skype* and click *details*.
3. Allow the app to run in background and also for even when battery
   saver is on.